# Are clustered standard error still possible if no panel data structure is available?

Tags: r, standard-error

The usage of CSE is usually linked to panel data. Should one still use it if the data structure is not a panel dataset but an event type structure?

Comment: Hi. How do you define an *event type* structure? It is always important to think about *how* you’re sampling observations when applying cluster-robust uncertainty estimators.

Comment: Its like Yi,t = β0 + β∗Aftert + ui,t; and the sample is fairly small; n<500, I could cluster along the cross section.

Comment: The *after* variable is *t* subscripted so I assume you are measuring something *through time*. Right? And yes, you could cluster on individuals if you believe there is “within-cluster” dependence, but it would depend on *how* they were sampled. Is there some type of study design you have in mind?

Comment: Even if the individuals occur only once in the whole sample, I could cluster them? Sampled by whom? They are selected by investors that represent the whole population.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes. You can cluster outside of a panel data framework. For starters, how the standard errors are influenced by clustering should never be the reason why you cluster. Of principal importance is *how the sample of individuals was selected*.

Without the specifics of how investors selected individuals in the population, it is difficult to advise you how to proceed. Here is something to think about. Did investors choose participants by first randomly sampling a set of firms in a given country, *and then* randomly sampling individuals *within* those firms? Or, did investors randomly select firms, *and then* randomly select mid-level executives from *within* those firms? In the former case, you may want to make inferences about the broader population of firms. In that case, you may want to cluster on firm.

If you have aggregate data, clustering at that level of aggregation is often advised. Outside of a panel data framework, we could still have observations that are related within certain groups. Students/children nested *within* classrooms is a classic example. Suppose you want to investigate the effect of classroom size on academic performance (i.e., grades). The model is specified as follows

$$
\textrm{Grades}_{ig} = \gamma_{0} + \gamma_{1} \textrm{Size}_{ig} + u_{ig},
$$

where $i$ indexes individual students and $g$ indexes the students' group. Note the possibility of within-cluster (classroom) correlation across students. Let's assume independence across classrooms for the sake of this example. Think about why observations (students) *within* a cluster (classroom) might be related (e.g., teacher quality). The 'quality instruction' unobservable might affect students individually within a group. But, we should be more concerned about unobservables affecting *collections of students* in the same way (uniformly), *within a group*. That is, $\textrm{E}\left[u_{ig} u_{jg'}\right] = \sigma_{(ij)g}$ if $g = g'$. If the errors are positively correlated within a cluster, then a new student introduced into the cluster does not provide an independent piece of new information. Failing to account for this may result in standard errors that are too small.

Based upon your question, it doesn't appear that investors are randomly sampling from the entire population. They may want a specific type of individual, not *any* individual. If *everyone* has an equal (non-zero) probability of selection, then you shouldn't concern yourself with clustering.